# Column A numbers matched with Column B numbers that are assigned to Column C =column D?

Tags: excel, matching, vlookup

This is my example

1. Column A are numbers
2. Column B are numbers
3. Column C are Names

The A column are numbers associated with a item sold to one place. Column B is the items sold and C is the person who sold them. I would like column D to show the item sold to this one place and who sold it. Let me know if that makes sense.

PS: Column A has 1304 rows. Column B and C have 6154 rows

Comment: Can you give us an example of the content and of the result?

Comment: well im not sure, i have figures for what was sold to 1 location then i have figures for everything that was sold and by who. The B and C and are all the sales and by who and A is the sales to specific location. I'm looking for a way to get those specific sales to that location stripped out and with who sold them.

Comment: Why column A and B have different number of rows? Are they two independent tables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is hard to guess what your data looks like, so assuming your data looks as below:

[image]

Here is my solution, I think it is a simple `VLOOKUP` problem:
Paste this `=IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(C2,$A$2:$A$4,1,FALSE)),"","SoldToPlaceA")` to `E2` and drag it down to copy.